# VSCode Auto-Import doesn't work: Cannot find name

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxt3

I have just upgraded Nuxt 3.1 to 3.2...

[image]

How to make it work properly? (starting server can be successful)

Comment: Try to run `npx nuxi clean` and restart your dev server. Then check that the `.nuxt/types/imports.d.ts` file is created and includes `defineNuxtComponent`.

Comment: I tried this and also the volar restart, but nothing helped. The imports file is generated properly though...

Comment: This situation has become increasingly frequent recently, especially when using Nuxt

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For me, I just had to do the following to restart the Vetur extension and make it recognize the auto-imports again:

> CTRL + SHIFT + P
>
> > Volar: Restart Vue Server